Using pipreqs in pyenv virtualenv writes requirements.txt with numpy version that is not in virtualenv
I use PyEnv to manage Python virtual environments. I have numpy 1.26.4 installed in my project environment. If I run
pip list

from my activated virtualenv, I get
notebook                  7.2.1
notebook_shim             0.2.4
numpy                     1.26.4
opt-einsum                3.3.0
overrides                 7.7.0

Now I run the following from my project folder, also from my activated virtualenv:
pipreqs .

This gives the output
numpy==2.0.0
opt_einsum==3.3.0

It seems that pipreqs fetches the latest version of numpy it finds on PyPI, without regards to the versions in my environment. Can I restrict pipreqs to only write versions I have in my environment to requirements.txt?
It would seem odd if it couldn't, since these versions are the ones I use for development.
I'm running this on macOS Sonoma 14.1.1 with Apple M2 Max processor.
